# iOS (Swift) : How to reduce space in between two LeftBarButtonItems of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to customize my `UINavigationBar`. Now I want to reduce the space in between of two `LeftBarButtonItems` of `UINavigationBar` in Swift. (Please refer screenshot)

Code as follows :

```
    // Back Button
    let leftButton1: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    leftButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50) ;
    leftButton1.setImage(UIImage(named:"back.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)        

    var leftBarButtonItem1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton1)

    // App Logo
    let leftButton2: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    leftButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30) ;
    leftButton2.setImage(UIImage(named:"app_logo.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    var leftBarButtonItem2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftButton2)


    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftBarButtonItem1, leftBarButtonItem2], animated: true)
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you change the width is in -negative just like  leftButton2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, - 30, 30) ; it ignore the standard width

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Bad luck, It doesn't work.